# How can I create a set containing both int and float numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I want to create a set containing both integers and floats. Something like this:

```
s = {4, 6.7, 2.12, 9}
```

However, I ran into something unexpected (at least to me): I cannot add both `9` (an integer) and `9.0` (a float). Here is an example:

```
>>> s = {4, 6.7, 2.12, 9}
>>> s
{9, 2.12, 4, 6.7}
>>> s.add(9.0)
>>> s
{9, 2.12, 4, 6.7}
```

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I add *both* numbers to my set?

I don't want `9.0 in s` to hold true if I did not add the float number to my set. I really can't figure out how to do it.

As a side note, I noticed that this is true also with keys of a dictionary. So I can't map `3` and `3.0` to different values.

Comment: You can't. Python treats them as equivalent: `print(9 == 9.0)`

Comment: Why not store them as strings? that should technically allow you to store both `9` and `9.0` in that case

Comment: @Barmar So should I somehow re-implement (or subclass?) the set class?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco ... we would need to understand why you need this functionality ... but creating a new type of "set" class is maybe one possibility ... chances are there is a better way to handle it

Comment: You could make a set of tuples `(x, type(x).__name__)`

Comment: Rather than store them as strings, store then as tuples: (value, class). For example, `s.add((9.0, type(9.0)))`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Those numbers are the result of different operations (whose result is float or int), and I care about their type because I want to associate to them different behaviours once I pick them from the set

Comment: Convert your entry in string format and when you accessing the item, convert back to your required dtype.

Comment: Could you "associate to them different behaviours" *before* you put them into the set? I.e., like the suggested tuples but with the "behaviour" instead of the type.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, they're all very useful, especially the one from @Booboo

Comment: Or perhaps one set for ints, one for floats?

Answer (score 4):

In Python `9.0 == 9` and equality is the basis for uniqueness in sets.

If you want equal `float` and `int` numbers *not* to collide in your `set` you actually have *two* properties for comparison: the value, and the type.

The simplest solution is simply to store them both in the set, using a `tuple`. For example

```py
s = set()
s.add( (float, 1.0) )
s.add( (float, 5.0) )
s.add( (int, 5) )
s.add( (float, 5.0) )
```

Simple but a bit awkward, and relies on you to set the correct type: there's nothing to stop you adding a `float` using an `int` value. Alternatively, you could implement a `set` subclass that handles the magic for you

```py
class TypedSet(set):
   
   def add(self, v):
       vtype = type(v)
       super().add( (vtype, v) )

   def remove(self, v):
       vtype = type(v)
       super().remove( (vtype, v) )


s = TypedSet()
s.add(1.0)
s.add(5.0)
s.add(5)
s.add(5.0)
```

*Note: for a real implementation this will need a lot more work.*

The above will produce the following set (note the duplicate 5.0 behaves as expected).

```
TypedSet({(<class 'float'>, 1.0), (<class 'int'>, 5), (<class 'float'>, 5.0)})
```

So this is *possible*, but if I were you I'd stop and check whether *really you want to do this at all*. If you've got two things that you want to track, maybe what you want is **two sets**?

You can always combine the sets to a tuple when you need to iterate/work with them, e.g.

```py
my_floats = set()
my_ints = set()

my_floats.add(1.0)
my_floats.add(5.0)
my_ints.add(5)
my_floats.add(5.0)

combined = (*my_floats, *my_ints)  # combine to a tuple
```

Will give you the following (without any magic)...

```
(1.0, 5.0, 5)
```

Comment: `TypedSet` implementation will need a _lot_ more stuff to work without surprises (e.g. an update method, and overriding all the magic methods necessary for set operators).

Comment: Yep, I think it's a questionable idea so I didn't want to go any further with it -- added a note.

Answer (score 1):

`set` is fundamentally a hashtable. To handle collisions, it checks if the two objects with equal hashes are equal, and if they are, it just assumes the one it already has is correct. Or something along those lines.

The problem is that `floats` are integers have the same hashcode as the integers would. The hash of any sufficiently small integer in python is equal to that integer, incidentally.

Instead of re-implementing or subclassing `set`, it's easier to re-implement the `float` class to simply make its hash different from an integer:

```
class hfloat(float):
    def __hash__(self):
        if self == int(self):
            return hash((float, float.__hash__(self)))
        else:
            return float.__hash__(self)

s = {4, 6.7, 2.12, 9}
s.add(hfloat(9.0))
print(s)
# {2.12, 4, 6.7, 9, 9.0}
```

---

disclaimer: a `hfloat` and a `float` with the same integer value will now not have the same hash, so this could also happen:

```
s = {9.0, hfloat(9.0)}
print(s)
# {9.0, 9.0}
```

Doing as the comments suggest, and storing `(value, type)` 2-tuples in the hashtable might be better for your use case.

Comment: How safe is this?

Comment: Thanks, it definitely works!! :D

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Until you come across a number where it doesn't :-P

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode what do you mean? What numbers are you talking about?

Comment: I downvoted. *Any* arithmetic between an hfloat instance and another float is just going to return a float. This approach would necessitate the code which is populating the set to be very careful to only produce these magical hfloat instances. It's an ugly and fragile way around that will likely cause more issues than it solves. Instead, maintaining one set of integers and one set of floats would be simpler, easier and faster (the lookup could perhaps be unified using a ChainMap instance)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I mean floats that happen to get their regular hash this way so that they'll still have the problem you're talking about.

Comment: @wim In retrospect I agree. Write that as an answer and you'll get an upvote from me

Comment: It's also documented in the [datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) that `__hash__`  requires objects which compare equal have the same hash value, and you *intentionally* break that.

Comment: [simpler and safe](https://tio.run/##NU1LCsMgFNy/UzzoRqlIaksbCz2LSKNYECM@uyghZ7dJmg7DLObD5E8NYzr3ubT2jJYIg4@jrWxTfgdcMDiPxgRLwRhGLvrdX1FcfZeEa7hFeETFAQgfOF0EXuVNoJInJVDPQNIOA9sftOw4h1xeqTLicMDp1/uv9ELZza19AQ) (but still has the issues pointed out by wim).